# In Unity, can I expose C# *Properties* in the Inspector Window?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Scripts are normally written so that public *fields* are exposed in the Inspector; is there some way to use *properties* instead?

```
// instead of this
public GameObject wrongBall;

// is there some way to do this (to trigger an event in the setter, for instance)
// and have it show up in the inspector window?
public GameObject WrongBallProperty
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: Kinda incredible how Unity still doesn't have support for this after so many versions.

Comment: @RayKoopa the problem is serialization. It is easier to do serialization on fields than properties without any issues coming up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sort of.**

You can't directly use a property in the inspector, but you can create your property with a backing field:

```
public GameObject WrongBallProperty {
    get { return this.wrongBallProperty; }
    set { //do whatever }
}

[SerializeField]
private gameObject wrongBallProperty;
```

This will display `wrongBallProperty` in the inspector, and allow you to do whatever logic you need in `get` and `set`. See the [SerializeField reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) for more info.

Comment: Note, serializing the backing field will fail to call the property setter if you alter the field in the inspector.  This is because it is the field that is serialized and not the property.

Answer (score 42):

You can use [Auto-Implemented Property Field-Targeted Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.3/auto-prop-field-attrs) since Unity 2018.

```
[field: SerializeField]
public GameObject WrongBallProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: This answer is under rated :)

Comment: @Tacoタコス Much appreciated and glad it helps :)

Comment: I fear this is technically correct but not very helpful. It works for `{ get; set; }` which is essentially a fancy syntax for a plain-old field, but as soon as the setter has some actual logic attached (as the OP hinted in the comment) the `[field: ...]` attribute fails to compile.

Comment: @NorbertNemec If you've had to add the field manually anyway, what's to stop you putting `[SerializeField]` just above the field at that point?

Comment: @Dan personally I'd say there's nothing stopping you from doing so, however if I wanted my property to perform some action on setting, it would be nice for unity to be able to support this.

Comment: @RWolfe Thanks for the comment. I think I misunderstood Norbert's comment originally and hadn't considered extra logic in the set/get functions. I think you'd be able to achieve showing properties using a custom editor. I had a bit of a play around but it's not super simple to achieve and I didn't get very far. However, there appears to be at least one asset that promises this functionality. Unfortunately it is not free so I was unable to test it's functionality [Odin Inspector](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/odin-inspector-and-serializer-89041)

Comment: @RWolfe [Relevant Odin documentation page](https://odininspector.com/attributes/show-in-inspector-attribute)

Comment: @Dan I can't speak for anyone else, but at this time investing in Odin Inspector is not an option, it would be nice if specifically get/set properties could be exposed, perhaps through a `SerializePropertyAttribute` (so that not all get/set properties get exposed)

Comment: @RWolfe I agree. This issue with a custom property drawer for a property with an attribute above it, at least when I had a look yesterday, I couldn't get it to trigger for C# properties. It only seemed to trigger when the attribute was placed above a field, not properties or classes

Comment: @Dan The reason for that is Unity's Serialization process looks specifically for public fields, and private fields with the `SerializeFieldAttribute`, it ignores properties of any type.

Comment: @RWolfe Yep, that's why a custom editor rather than a custom property drawer is likely the way to go. You could possibly get it to target monobehaviour and all sub classes, then let it draw as normal, except add the fields for properties on the bottom

Comment: @Dan It seems quite excessive to have to do that, just to execute a simple 'validation' on a class that is neither a Monobehaviour or a ScriptableObject.