# I can't make an Array of Classes show on my Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I know this may sound a bit dumb since there are already some posts talking about it but none of the answers there seem to work on my case..

I have this simple project that will have a Quest system. For that I created a simple QuestObject script with a Item (custom class I've created) and a quantity.

**QuestObject:**

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class QuestObject
{
    public Item data { get; private set; }
    public int quant { get; private set; }

}
```

Then I have this other class with an Array of these QuestObjects.

**Quest:**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Quest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public QuestObject[] questItems;

    public bool complete;

    [TextArea(4, 10)]
    public string title, thankYou, charging, description;
}
```

The idea is to store which item(s) and its quantity are needed for each separate Quest to be complete. Each instance of the Quest script is in a NPC GameObject.

I want to be able to set the Array size and drag the Items and type its quantity on Inspector for each instance of the Quest script.

Everything seems to be correct.. Serializable class with public variables being called by a public array. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[Serializable]
public class QuestObject
{
    [field: SerializeField]
    public Item data { get; private set; }

    [field: SerializeField]
    public int quant { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! I didn't know there was a difference between [SerializeField] and [Field: SerializeField]! Apparently there is...

Answer (score 1):

Property can't directly be seen on Unity Inspector. You need to add `[field: SerializeField]` attribute to make it appear, see:

[In Unity, can I expose C# *Properties* in the Inspector Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554418/in-unity-can-i-expose-c-sharp-properties-in-the-inspector-window)

Also, make sure your `Item` class is attached with `[Serializeable]` attribute. Only when you add the Serializable attribute, Unity can display it in the Inspector via the reflection mechanism through meta data.